# Как передать данные между фрагментами с помощью setFragmentResult()?

Tags: android, kotlin

EditFragment должен получать текст от пользователя и передавать его в NotesFragment для добавления в список (recycleView). Хочу использовать setFragmentResult, но у меня ничего не выходит. Должна ли здесь быть задействована Activity? Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        startNotesFragment()

        initListeners()
    }


    private fun initListeners() {
        binding.bAdd.setOnClickListener {
            startEditFragment()
        }
    }

    private fun startEditFragment() {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fl_container, EditFragment.newInstance()).addToBackStack(null).commit()

    }

    private fun startNotesFragment() {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
            R.id.fl_container,
            NotesFragment.newInstance()
        ).addToBackStack(null).commit()

    }
}




class EditFragment : Fragment() {
    private var binding: FragmentEditBinding? = null

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = EditFragment()
    }
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = FragmentEditBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        return binding?.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding!!.bUndo.setOnClickListener {
            activity?.onBackPressed()
        }
        binding?.bSave?.setOnClickListener {
           val result = binding!!.etAuthorText.text.toString()
            setFragmentResult("key", bundleOf("bundleKey" to result))
            activity?.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        binding = null
    }

}



class NotesFragment : Fragment() {
    private var binding: FragmentListBinding? = null
    private val adapter = NoteAdapter()

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = NotesFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding!!.rcList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        binding!!.rcList.adapter = adapter
        setFragmentResultListener("key") { key, bundle ->
            val result = bundle.getString("bundleKey")
            if (result != null) {
                adapter.addNote(result)
            }
        }
    }
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return binding?.root

    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        binding = null
    }
}


class NoteAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.NoteHolder>() {
    private val noteList = ArrayList<String>()

    class NoteHolder(item: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {
        private val binding = MyListItemBinding.bind(item)
        fun bind(authorText: String) = with(binding) {
            tvMessage.text = authorText
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false)
        return NoteHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(noteList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return noteList.size
    }

    fun addNote(note: String) {
        noteList.add(note)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать supportFragmentManager вашего Activity.

Для отслеживания результата:

```
activity?.supportFragmentManager?.setFragmentResultListener(
        "key",
        viewLifecycleOwner,
        { requestKey, result ->
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        })
```

Для передачи данных:

```
activity?.supportFragmentManager?.setFragmentResult("key",  bundleOf("bundleKey" to result))
```